# Why are there suddenly hundreds of posts in the "Late Answers" review queue?

Tags: support, review

There are suddenly 300+ answers in the *Late Answers* review queue.

Mostly, they are answers to questions that were migrated here a looooong time ago. However, I'm seeing a fair share that aren't. They are all people with relatively low reputation here, so maybe the definition of "new user" for that queue changed?

Did somebody flip a switch, or was there a bug recently fixed that prevented these from getting into the queue in the first place?

Comment: Just now noticed and came here to ask the same question.

Comment: @serenesat, me too! I even got the screenshots ready!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be because this has been implemented:

[Can we raise the bar for reputation for late answers to enter the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266696/21960)

Essentially, the definition of "new user" for that queue has been raised to 50 reputation points from 10.

Comment: However, they're _supposed_ to be no older than a month, so something's a bit hinkey.